# How to write formatted text in JTextField dynamically, like Bold, Italic or with bullets and numbering?

Tags: java, swing

How can i set formatted text in JTextFiled , **as like when posting answer in this website we can change style of font and adding numbering etc.**

Comment: Have you tried googling for it? [First hit](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-jtextfield)

Comment: Use `JTextPane`. How you are going to fit multiple line in `JTextField`. 

**JTextField is a lightweight component that allows the editing of a single line of text.**

If you stick to `JTextField`, I should tell you it only supports fonts. You can try : `setFont()`.

Answer (score 0):

Google is your best help.  Steps to construct this will follow something similar.

```
1: Create identifier, some character combination/symbol to define what's what(bold, italicized, underlined).

2: When text is passed into your program have something that checks to see if your identifiers were used.  

3:  If you find and identifier, then use an if statement, switch or something to change the font to what you want and remove the identifier from your string.

4. Then display the string where you want it.
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question . You need to explain in detail so that other viewers are able to help you out.

1. Are you making your TextField as bold inputs?
2. Are you trying to make your textfield accept only numbers ?
3. Elaborate more on
   Bullets and numebering .

if you are trying to create your own inbuild function like textField accept only numbers.

You have to create a few java classes.
For an example

**template.java**

```
  private JTextField createText(boolean acceptOnlyNumbers){
     JTextField userInput;
        if(acceptOnlyNumbers != false){
             userInput.addKeyListener(new acceptNumberOnly(userInput))
        }
     return userInput;    
  }
```

You can create this within the same java class, but the best way is to asign your listener to a different class so that whenever you want to modify dynamically, you could just make changes to that file instead of searching it .

```
class acceptNumberOnly implements addKeyListener{
JTextField textField ;

public acceptNumberOnly(JTextField textField){
      this.textField = textField
}

textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    char c = e.getKeyChar();

if (!(Character.isDigit(c) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
                        e.consume();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

I feel this is one of the best practice to use, categorised your components as class. so you can reuse this components over and over again and codes will be much neater.